# How should a Windows application with custom controls be drawn with Direct2D?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, visual-c++

I would like to create a **Windows application** (for Windows 10) using the **C++** and the **Windows API**. I already have some basic knowledge of using the built-in windows controls to create a basic application, but would now like to expand into **custom controls** . Since I have no need for my application to be compatible with anything but Windows 10, and would like to use a reliable API which supports transparency and anti-aliasing but is also fast enough to render a GUI, I have chosen to use Direct2D.

The MSDN documentation says:

> ['Your application should create render targets once'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/getting-started-with-direct2d#:%7E:text=Your%20application%20should%20create%20render%20targets%20once%20and%20hold%20on%20to%20them%20for%20the%20life%20of%20the%20application%20or%20until%20the%20D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET%20error%20is%20received.)

Bearing this in mind, should each child window use one *ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* which renders only to the parent window (and doesn't respond to the child windows' *WM_PAINT* messages), or should there be a single *ID2D1DCRenderTarget* which would draw to each control using the device context from the *WM_PAINT* message (using *bindDC()* - although I would still like to be able to use transparency, and am not interested in GDI interoperability)? Should I even be using Direct2D at all?

I would like to use the Windows API, so a solution involving QT or MFC wouldn't work. I haven't got a specific application in mind, but would eventually like to create a simple library that would enable me to quickly produce GUI applications that have a custom look.

I have spent hours scouring the web for answers, but have found nothing conclusive. MSDN itself seems particularly unhelpful, it just teaches you to draw an ellipse and stops there. Please forgive me if I have accidentally broken the rules of asking questions - as you can probably tell I am new to *Stack Overflow* - and if any other information is needed, I will of course include it (I am using C++ with Visual Studio Community 2019).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? What were the errors?

Comment: If you don't need GDI, forget it, it's legacy. You should have a look at WinUI3 (not before version 3). It's in preview but fills most tech gaps and supports (hopefully) classic win32 desktop apps. Otherwise, you can use the Windows composition engine: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/july/windows-with-c-embracing-the-windows-composition-engine and here a minimal Windows app with this technology: https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec then you can use Direct2D to draw inside Composition visuals. WinUI3 uses composition engine too.

Comment: @starturtle I have managed to draw shapes on a single hwnd using Direct2D with no problem. There is no error (yet), but I am trying to ask what the best method of painting custom controls is so that I don't spend hours doing it wrong.

Comment: @sim The GDI is still **substantially** faster than any other of those technologies for the vast majority of UI's. The only case where D2D/DirectComposition are superior is in producing smoother (yet not necessarily faster) animation effects. A UI that isn't animated is best done using GDI, even today.

Comment: @IInspectable - I never said anything about performance, but performance depends on what you do and how you do it. Do you have any proof of your "substantially faster for the vast majority of UI" assertion?

Comment: @sim Proof, such as profiling? Sure. I've been profiling GDI code ever since Direct2D was a thing, specifically response times. Direct2D got better over time, though most of the performance improvements were due to Direct2D starting out with complete garbage performance. But still today, you aren't getting any faster than GDI with respect to response times.

Comment: In Direct2D,  resource creation and deletion on hardware are expensive operations because they require lots of overhead for communicating with the video card.  So reuse resources when possible. For your drawing in the custom control, you can share all device-independent resources created by a factory with all other resources (device-independent or device-dependent) created by the same factory. See: [Sharing Factory Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/resources-and-resource-domains#sharing-factory-resources)